# How to uninstall broken programs in windows 7

Tags: windows-7, uninstall

Could anyone tell me how to uninstall programs that their installation had a problem and therefore their uninstall doesn't work?

I removed all their references in the registry and their folder on the hdd but still don't know how to get rid of them completely from Add/Remove Programs list.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I used [Revo uninstaller](http://www.revouninstaller.com/) to fix it.